# wav file wrote from inputStream not playable

Tags: java, wav, file-conversion

I write the inputStream in wav file format, the file is being written but when i try to open file its not playing, i think its corrupted. How to see or debug where i am falling short. Any help is appreciated.

```
    InputStream speechStream= null;
    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource=null;   

    try{
        speechStream=quikWitService.getPollyTextToSpeech(voiceId,text,outputFormat);
        inputStreamResource= new InputStreamResource(speechStream);




        File audioFile = new File("D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/webapps/QuikWit/hello.wav");     

        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2 * 1024];
            int readBytes;
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(audioFile);
            try (InputStream in = speechStream){
                    while ((readBytes = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                   }
               }
            outputStream.close();
        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't process the audio");
        }
        System.out.println("Success");      




    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.error(e);
        logger.debug(e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: Does `getPollyTextToSpeech` return WAV encoded byte data?

Comment: @Kayaman its return InputStream

Comment: I know that, but what type is the data that is coming from the inputstream? You're writing it out as if it's a valid `.wav` file, but that's unlikely. You need something like  [AudioFileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/AudioFileWriter.html) to generate valid files.